# how to open by default p-panelMenu

Tags: angular, primeng

My english is very poor. but  how to expand or open p-panelMenu by default

```
 <p-panelMenu [model]="items" id="myPanel" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [multiple]="true" ></p-panelMenu>
```

I need this menu is opened by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `expanded` attribute

Set `expanded: true` in your respective array,

Stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-px2sek

Comment: Hi ng-suhas. A lot of thanks it´s solve this issue or my problem.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Quiles Estruch Happy to help :)